# How to convert from windows-1257 to utf-8 (mysql)

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm looking for a help with encoding problem I've been struggling for couple days now already.

I have a database with Collation "latin1_swedish_ci". When I view a single entry it shows a messed up text

```
grieþos informçs
```

it should be

```
griežos informēs
```

Ok so... I tried to output text into browser with php script and set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1257" />
```

Now... it shows data correctly ("griežos informēs"). What I need to do is convert this data to UTF-8 so I can use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and get everything displayed correctly.

I tried to use Notepad2 and create a file with encoding windows-1257 then copy text from database and save it.... same problem.

Tried to even create a table in that database with utf-8 collation and insert data there... no luck - just shows ? where special chars should be.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(_cp1257_general_ci'test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
```

(test is the column name)

That will get you the row in the proper character set. You should create a new table using UTF8 then `SELECT CAST(....) FROM old_table INTO new_table`

You may also want to change the character set of the old table to cp1257_general_ci instead of latin1_swedish_ci.

In order to do it without losing data first change the datatype of the column to `blob`, then change it a second time to varchar with the cp1257_general_ci, then finally a third time to utf8_unicode_ci (I suggest a backup first, just in case.)

Comment: No, I meant that for the second time :( Sorry. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query right after you open your connection to your database so you run it once on every page load :

```
    mysql_query('SET NAMES `utf8`');
```

Comment: That won't help him because the defined character set of the column does not match the character set of the actual data, so MySQL will not be able to convert it to utf8.